# How to check if a Stripe Error exists / puts a Stripe Error if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In my Rails applications, I am trying to only run a Stripe Charge command IF a Stripe Error does not exist.  And I want to be able to inspect the Stripe Error.

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
  :amount => amount_in_cents,
  :customer => stripe_customer,
  :description => "my application",
)
```

Should be something like:

```
unless Stripe.errors.exists? do
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => amount_in_cents,
      :customer => stripe_customer,
      :description => "my application",
   )
end
```

And to be confident my code is working, I am trying to `puts` the Stripe Error, if it exists.  Is the Stripe Error an object that I can `puts`?

Such as:

```
if Stripe.error.exists?
    puts Stripe.error
end
```

Trying to see the output with `puts` commands in my model, as well as in my testing file like so:

To intentionally create an error:

```
StripeMock.prepare_card_error(:card_declined)
```

Me trying to `puts` this (but none of the below works):

```
puts "Stripe Card Error: #{Stripe::CardError}"

begin
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  body = e.json_body
  err  = body[:error]
  puts err.exists?
  puts err
end

puts err.exists?
puts err
```

When I try something like:

```
error = Stripe::CardError
if error
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
end
```

it is not valid, and neither are `if Stripe.error` or `if Stripe::CardError` or `if Stripe::CardError.exists?`.

There must be some Stripe Error `object` that we can apply logic to?!?

Any help on `puts`ing / inspecting the Stripe Error would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to see the `stack trace` of Stripe error?

Comment: @mehedi I want to be able to run code only if an error exists. 

Something like:   `if Stripe::CardError`    -->     `rescue Stripe::CardError => e`   -->  `end`

But that is not valid, and neither are `if Stripe::CardError` or `if Stripe::CardError.exists?`.

And I would love to be able to inspect the error.

Comment: You should attempt to do the charge within your `being ... rescue ... end` block and use the various error classes on the `rescue` part. Here's a [small example](https://github.com/TestingPays/stripe_rails_example/blob/master/app/controllers/concerns/stripe_handler_module.rb) on how we've done it with an example app, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off the comments on the original question: you want to catch the exception thrown by `Stripe::charge.create()`.

```rb
begin
  puts "About to create charge"
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => amount_in_cents,
    :customer => stripe_customer,
    :description => "my application",
  )
  # The next line only runs if Charge.create() did not raise an exception

  puts "Created charge #{charge.id}"
  MyDatabase.insert(charge.id)

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # An error was thrown, so execution of the begin block did not complete
  puts e
end
```

Here's [a brief tutorial on exception handling in Ruby](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html).

Comment: Thanks. Also it sounds like the `object` I have been looking for is actually "`e`" in both of our code examples.